# 3d wireframe plot matplotlib/ different length arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, wireframe

I'm trying to visualize data with a 3d wireframe plot, but the plot does not work with different length arrays. Here is an equal-length array example that does work:

```
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    x=[1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5]
    y=[2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5]
    zuniques, z = np.unique(['foo', 'baz', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz','bar'], 
    return_inverse=True)

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1)

    ax.set(zticks=range(len(zuniques)), zticklabels=zuniques)

    plt.show()
```

Now how can I make the x, y and z arrays different length and still use the wireframe chart? 
There has to be a way to visualize the three axes in 3D even if they are not the same length.

Like if you had percent gains/losses displayed on the x axis, a few months on the y axis and a hundred ticker symbols on the z axis.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Each point will have to be defined with three coordinates in 3d space. If the three arrays have different lengths, how do you know which x goes with which y or z?

Comment: Instead of showing a working example of something you don't want to have you would need to show a (non-working) example of the actual case you have. Be very specific, because as has been mentionned, it's not obvious what the expected plot for unequal number of coordinates should look like. (Think in 2 dimensions, having `x = [1,2,3]`, `y = [5,6]`, what should the last x-coordinate (`3`) relate to?)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I see now why the different lengths are a problem. Each point must have 3 coordinates. But is it possible to change the way the arrays are plugged in to the function to the show the kind of gain/loss data I described above in a wire frame chart? I read somewhere that the plot_wireframe() function inputs can be 2D arrays. Can that be a part of the solution? Also, a 3D column chart could be another good way to do what I'm trying to do- https://ibb.co/n7PMRQ  I realize that the different array lengths and column chart axis lengths are not the same thing.